# Problem with printing value in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

This code sample is about phonegap. I'm having a problem printing inside the `for` loop.

Any idea why is this happening?

```
var html = "<table id='tableData' border='1'><tr><td>ID</td><td>Data</td></tr>";
var len = results.rows.length;
for (var i=0; i<=len; i++){
    html += "<tr><td>" + results.rows.item(i).id + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + results.rows.item(i).data + "</td></tr>";

}
html += "</table>";
$('#content').html(html);
```

Comment: what "problem" is it that you have?

Comment: Change `for (var i=0; i<=len; i++){` to: `for (var i=0; i<len; i++){` with such code you'll get error in the last iteration as you're overflowing out of the array upper bound.

Comment: *Any idea why is this happening?* What?

Comment: The values of results.rows.item(i).id is not printing!!

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said ***what*** the problem is, but this line is probably incorrect:

```
for (var i=0; i<=len; i++)
```

You probably meant `<`, not `<=`:

```
for (var i=0; i<len; i++)
```

...because with your original code, `i` will go from `0` to `len` **inclusive**, so if you have (say) five rows, on the last loop you'll be trying to access `result.rows.item(5)`, which is the *sixth* item assuming that `result.rows.item(0)` is the first item (which would be fairly standard). Arrays and collections either go from `0..length-1` or from `1..length`, depending (usually `0..length-1`, but it depends on what `result.rows` is).